# How to forward to a specific part of a JSP page in java Servlet

Tags: html, css, jsp, servlets

In Test.java:

...
...
request.getRequestDispatcher("Test.jsp").forward(request, response);

---

How to make it so it jumps to a specific part of the Test.jsp page. Let say, the 15th row of a large table.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an internal page anchor.

In the file that redirects to Test.jsp add this:

```
<script>
var loc = window.location.href;
window.location.href= loc+"#row-15";
</script>
```

Next, in Test.jsp

```
<tr><td> <a id="row-15">row 15 data here.</a> </td></tr>
```

[Working fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/yda9maL2/4/)

It doesn't have to be Javascript by the way, as long as the anchor "a" tag is present where you want the page to scroll to and the url has the id of the a tag.

Comment: My mistake. I forgot to add an internal anchor in the row. I'll update my post.

Comment: I have solved the problem with my friend's help in a way that is similar to what you suggested. I will upload my solution later tonight. Thanks for your effort.